# Using spectral coherence for computing similarity between time series data

Tags: coherence

I don't really know anything about signal processing. I need to find similairty between two 1-dimensional time series. I read somewhere that spectral coherence could be used to find similarity between two time series. But i am not able to get around how to use it. Can some one tell how i can use it to compute similarity between time series.

Comment: did you ever get this issue resolved because I have the same problem and I would like to source C code for this analysis?

Comment: @Ben : I will try to answer this question shortly, perhaps you can add a comment here (or edit your deleted "answer") about what your requirements are?

Comment: @Ben Try that answer.

Answer (score 3):

One way to check for similarity between time series is to use the cross-correlation:
$$
\rho_{xy}(\tau) = \frac{1}{\sigma_x \sigma_y} E[ (x[n] - \mu_x)(y[n] - \mu_y) ] 
$$
where $\mu_{x,y}$ is the mean of $x$ or $y$ and $\sigma_{x,y}$ is the standard deviation of $x$ or $y$.

This gives us a value between -1 (completely anti-correlated) and +1 (completely correlated).

Sometimes, this doesn't work as well as we'd like because there is some filtering operation relating the two time series, so while there is a strong relationship between the two time series, the cross-correlation is not very close to 1.

As a result, the spectral coherence is sometimes used:
$$
C_{xy}(f) = \frac{|G_{xy}(f)|^2}{G_{xx}(f)G_{yy}(f)}
$$
where $G_{km}$ is the cross-spectral density between $k$ and $m$.

This is now a function of frequency, and the closer it is to 1 at a given frequency, the closer the two signals are related.

I've put together a simple example in `R` which illustrates the difference between cross-correlation and (spectral) coherence.

The top graph shows the two time series.  The middle graph shows the cross-correlation is less than 1.  The bottom graph shows the spectral coherence as a function of frequency.

[image]

You can see that the time series are not as similar in the higher frequencies as they are at low frequency.

Sometimes, the integral of these values is used over a limited bandwidth so that a single figure of similarity is arrived at.

---

**R Code Below**

```
  #15466

  x1 <- rnorm(1000)

  h <- c(1,3,2,1)/7
  x2 <- filter(x1,h, circular=TRUE) + rnorm(1000)/10

  par(mfrow=c(3,1))

  plot(x1,type="l",col="blue")
  lines(x2, col="green",lwd=5)
  title("Original and filtered noise signals")

  ccf(x1,x2)

  Ixy <- spectrum(cbind(x1,x2), plot=FALSE,spans=c(5,7))

  plot(Ixy$coh)h)
```

Comment: Hi Peter, would you be so kind to expand on the explanation "the integral of these values is used over a limited bandwidth"? Do you mean for instance in your last graph averaging the MSC values between 0 and 200 Hz? Thank you

Comment: @VMMF Yes: If there's a known bandwidth of interest, just sum / integrate over that range to get a single number or figure of merit.